# /usr/local/ Ownership Overwritten on CentOS Cpanel

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, apache-http-server, ownership

I have run the command `chown -R myuser:myuser /usr/local/` on a VPS machine running CentOS with CPanel installed. This has overwritten all the ownership in the apache, cpanel, php install folders and apache has complained about permissions when starting:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 341 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
SuexecUserGroup configured, but suEXEC is disabled: Invalid owner or file mode for /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec
```

I was wondering the best was to restore the owner permissions without resetting the box or falling back on a backup.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be to reset permissions using yum or rpm by running a verify with yum. This will tell you what packages will be out, and hopefully could track it down to the /usr/local/ directory.

```
$ yum -a -V
```